# Question: For what value of $c$ will $P(x)= -2x^3+cx^2-5x+2$ have the same remainder when devided by $x+1$ or $x-2$?

Tags: functions, polynomials, factoring, binomial-theorem, multinomial-coefficients

> For what value of $c$ will $P(x)= -2x^3+cx^2-5x+2$ have the same remainder when devided by $x+1$ or $x-2$?

No idea where to start with this one. Can't use the remainder theorem to find the remainder because of the leading coefficient and can't find the value of c when I have no known remainder. Be nice if the examples in my schools lessons actually included the same kind of questions that are on the tests but I guess that would make to much sense for school.

Comment: If you divide $ P(x) $ by $ x-a$, the remainder is $ P(a)$.

Comment: I see no reason why the leading coefficient would be an impediment here. If you're unsure, though, let $A(x)=P(x)/(-2)$. Then you have a polynomial with leading coefficient $1$.

Answer (score 2):

> **Remainder theorem**:
> When $P(x)$ is divided for $(x-k)$, the remainder is $P(k)$

Dividing by $(x+1)$ the remainder is $P(-1)$ and dividing by $(x-2)$ is $P(2)$

So we need to set
$$P(-1)=P(2)\to 9+c=-24 + 4 c\to c=11$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: use polynomial long division to divide $P(x)$ by $x+1$, and find the remainder term in terms of $c$. Then, divide $P(x)$ by $x-2$, and also find the remainder term in terms of $c$. Set the two remainder terms equal and solve...